# Am i physical body?

Tags: philosophy

Physical body always change with time.
But I can't say this is me because  I am not child now.
I am Not teen now.
I am lose with time slowly slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Your physical body counts as one of the five aggregates (skandha-rupa). As such it's considered impermanent, a source for craving/clinging, and therefore problematic to be identified with.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.109.than.html

Answer (score 1):

Buddha said people take at least one of the five aggregate as self. Which is called the five clinging-aggregate. This is one of the wrong views or Sakkhaya Dithi. It appears you take mind (one of the five aggregates) as the self.